# How to pass both image file and object with values from React and retrieve it on the Node.js (express) server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multipartform-data, multer

My goal is to send a request from my React app to my Express server with image file and object with some values. On the server I want to save image to the filedisk and use rest of tha data as always I would do with `req.body` 
So i appended the image and the data into FormData object and sent request to the server.
I use Multer to save the image to the filedisk and it works good, but the problem is that I cannot retrieve rest of my data: (because of this)

```
[Object: null prototype] { document: '{"name":"Thomas","address":"page.com"}' }
```

Client side code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('document', JSON.stringify({ name: "Thomas", address: "page.com" }));
formData.append('image', image);

axios.post('/api/add-user-with-avatar', formData)
```

Server side code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).fields([
  { name: 'image' },
  { name: 'document' }
]);

router.post('/add-user-with-avatar', (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);

    console.log('BODY: ', req.body);
    console.log('FILE: ', req.files);
  });
});
```

My questions:

1. What is the proper way to send a request from React with both image and other data? Should it be done with FormData? And how?
2. How to get the rest of my data in Express (e.g object with text values)?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1**

You need to convert your images to Base64 and pass it along with other objects to your Server. For base 64, You can you [react-file-base64](https://github.com/BosNaufal/react-file-base64)

**Answer 2**

To get the req data  from React app to Node js you can simply get the `req.body`. Sample code is like bellow:

```
createPost = (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post(req.body);
    //here in post variable, you have all the json data along with your Base64 image
};
```

Comment: From what I read everyone use FormData for that and images converted to Base64 are 33% larger. Are you sure this is the best way to do it?

Comment: Base64 dont increase image size. Its just a large string in Base64 format.